# set an age limit in a form in react js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, if-statement

The user cannot be less than 0 years old, and more than 100 years old

`//format birthday date req.validated.birthdate = moment(req.validated.birthdate, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `moment().diff`

```js
const ageInYears = moment().diff(moment('15/11/1993', "DD/MM/YYYY"), 'years');

if (ageInYears > 100) {
  alert('More than 100 years old')
} else if (ageInYears < 0) {
  alert('Less than 0 years old')
} else {
  alert('Age is fine')
}
```

Edit: Better code

Comment: it work for me without the 'years'. Thanks for you response.